# BlockingCollection that doesn't try again within 10 seconds

Tags: c#, multithreading, fifo, blockingcollection

I am using a `Blockingcollection` as a `FIFO queue` but I am doing a lot of operations on files, where the `consumer` may easily encounter a file lock, so what I have done is created a simple try catch where the consumer re-queue's itself, but in a long `FIFO queue` with lots of other Items in the queue this is enough of a pause, but in an empty or very short `FIFO queue` it means the `consumer` perpetually hammers the queue with repeating re-occurrences of itself that are probably going to be still file locked.

i.e.

`consumer busy` -> requeue -> `consumer busy`  -> requeue (ad infinitum)

is there a way to get the `BlockingCollection` to not attempt to run the new consumer if it is less than 10 seconds old? i.e. potentially get the net one in the queue and carry on and only take the next consumer if it's createdDateTime is null (default for first attempt) or if it is > 10 seconds?

Comment: Why don't you wait 10 seconds before you re-queue your item?

Comment: thanks @YuvalItzchakov, that is sub optimum because it means the queue is likely to be needlessly idle in a long queue scenario

Comment: Why would the queue be idle if you delay the re-insertion? You can re-queue it on a different thread if necessary.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov It becomes a little complex, because to do it, you would have to pause the worker for 10 seconds, or create a new worker (a new thread) that has as its only work to put the element in the queue...

Comment: On a sidenote... I hope that your queue is an infinite queue, because if workers can re-add items to it, then the "main" writer can't close it, because it doesn't know if the workers have other items to re-add (it can't use `CompleteAdding()`)

Comment: @xanatos I don't seem to understand why that's complex?

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov It isn't complex... it is resource-wasteful... You create a thread to do a very simple operation. I normally consider it wrong.

Comment: @xanatos Don't allocate a new resource each time. If it's a common scenario, have one thread do the allocations of objects that need re-queuing.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov Yep... I was thinking exactly of this... I've written a response with this idea.

Comment: yes, @xanatos the queue doesn't close, it is always stays available, because multiple threads need to send work to it

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov I see what you mean, a 2nd queue to pause and re-insert, that is a reasonable solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could keep two blocking collections: the main one and the "delayed" one. One worker thread would only work on the delayed one, readding them to the main collection. The signature of the rejected collection would be something like:

```
BlockingCollection<Tuple<DateTime, YourObject>>
```

now... If the time is fixed at 10 seconds, the delayed collection will nearly be `DateTime` sorted (in case of items added nearly at the same time this could be not-true, but we are speaking of milliseconds difference... not a problem)

```
public class MainClass
{
    // The "main" BlockingCollection
    // (the one you are already using)
    BlockingCollection<Work> Works = new BlockingCollection<Work>();

    // The "delayed" BlockingCollection
    BlockingCollection<Tuple<DateTime, Work>> Delayed = new BlockingCollection<Tuple<DateTime, Work>>();

    // This is a single worker that will work on the Delayed collection
    // in a separate thread
    public void DelayedWorker()
    {
        Tuple<DateTime, Work> tuple;

        while (Delayed.TryTake(out tuple, -1))
        {
            var dt = DateTime.Now;

            if (tuple.Item1 > dt)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(tuple.Item1 - dt);
            }

            Works.Add(tuple.Item2);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @MrHeelis Remember that this will work only if the delay is fixed! (10 secs for example). If you want variable delay, you can't do it this way.

Comment: @xantos no, that's ok this is for MD5 summing if the file is locked it can sleep and re-sleep so long as the queue is keeping trying without hammering the loop endlessly it's ok

Answer (score 3):

There's nothing built-in to help with that. Store with each work item the `DateTime` when it was last attempted (could be `null` if this is the first attempt). Then, in your processing function wait for `TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10) - (DateTime.UtcNow - lastAttemptDateTime)` seconds before making the next attempt.

Consider switching to a priority queue that stores items in the order of earliest next attempt datetime.